# Run terminal from php script

Tags: php

I have a server setup that will run locally on a raspberry pi.  I have everything working except the terminal script.  What I am trying to do is that after the form is submitted it launches the terminal and runs the command that will run until the pi is reset or window is closed.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('./start.sh');
echo $output;

?>
```

And the contents of start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash


cd /var/www/html/scoreboard/node/score/mscl-scrapper
lxterminal -e sudo  xvfb-run -a node mvcc.js
```

I can run this in terminal and it works just fine.  These are in the same directory whcih is within the server root.  How can I execute this command?

Comment: That doesn't run "in the terminal" though, does it? It requires a running `DISPLAY=` server.

Comment: @mario No I dont need a display to run this.  It runs headless.

Comment: xfvb probably, but lxterminal certainly doesn't.